# Subversion - add time stamp to file

Tags: svn

With subversion, when i commit a file, can it automatically append a commented out time stamp to the bottom of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for how to set an $Id$ comment, much like CVS does? It seems like it'll meet your needs, and there are instructions for doing so here:

http://www.startupcto.com/server-tech/subversion/setting-the-id-tag